# Gemoro Aliba Dehilchoso Guides

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, product-recommendation

Is anyone aware of a resource (book/website) that is a guide/reference for someone learning pieces of Gemoro in the context of it's halachic ramifications (Aliba Dehilchoso).

For example it will take a sugya in Shabbos and reference the relevant Rishonim on the Daf and then the necessary Meforshim on the Tur, Shulchan Aruch etc.

Comment: Did you ever learn the [Aruch Hashulchan on Shabbos](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan,_Orach_Chaim_242.1)...?

Answer (score 4):

The 'Mesivta' editions of Gemora by Oiz VeHadar have a section in back called Aliba Dehilchoso, it's fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a website called https://olamot.net/shiurim and each week they take a different sugya and go through it from the gamara down till modern-day posikem. Each week they have a different topic. (currently, they have over 550 topics)

Answer (score 1):

The one volume עיניים למשפט השלם by רבי יצחק אריאלי corrects the עניים למשפט in the Vilna Shas. That author  has a number of volumes devoted to study of individual tractates from the standpoint of discussion of halachic ramifications at length. Also please see the הלכה ברורה ובירור הלכה in which a number of other tractates are similarly discussed at length with that approach.

Comment: עניים למשפט you mean עין משפט? Also what do you mean "corrects"?

Comment: Rav Arieli wrote a single volume work in which he corrected errors and filled in omissions in the Vilna Shas version of the Ein LeMishpat (and I stand corrected as to the name of the original in the Vilna Shas). He also wrote several volumes on a few mesechtot in which he explained how the respective poskim understood those mesechtot.  Members of the kollel at Merkaz HaRav have published volumes on a few mesechtot titled Halacha Berurah that have that type of approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try dafyomi.co.il which summarizes the sugya then brings relevant Rishonim and Poskim. It is organized Daf by Daf.

See an example [here](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/sukah/halachah/su-hl-036.htm). You can get to other topics from the [homepage](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/).

Answer (score -2):

Are you familiar with Sefaria.org? You can open the Gemara, then click on a paragraph to choose to see either Rishonim or the places in Rambam or Tur or Shulchan Aruch where it is quoted, and then open those resources to see their respective commentaries.

Comment: It sounds like they want it filtered to only the parts that are halacha lemaaseh

Comment: @robev Never actually said lemaaseh, just halacha

Comment: The mesivta gemoro has a part that does something similar available on the otsar.